# How do I have text and a CircleAvatar across from each other (opposite sides), just below the appbar?

Tags: dart, flutter

Sorry guys (really new to flutter and dart) but I was wondering how I could have a CircleAvatar on the right side of the screen (below the app bar) and some text on the left side, just across from it. Thanks in advance for your help! I have pasted the code that I made for the text on the left side (below the appbar). I know its probably a super simple question to most of you guys but for me it's not because I haven't gotten to grips with dart/flutter yet.

```
body: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
                child: new Text(
                   'My Briefing',
                    style:
                    new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: We can try to wrap our Text and CircleAvatar widgets with a Row widget and set the mainAxisAlignment parameter of the Row widget to spaceBetween like this: `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. Row widget will put space between these two widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do what you are looking for:

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
          child: Text(
            'My Briefing',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        CircleAvatar(),
      ],
    )
```

By the way, starting dart 2, you can drop the "new" key word at the begging of each newly created classes.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for, thanks! (And I’ll start removing the “new” key words now.

Comment: @ctt103 I'm glad I was able to help! accepting my answer would be appreciated!